# Work flow of grouping in Sed

Tags: sed

Can anyone explain how grouping works with sed. I am following "Sed and Awk 101" book.

This concept looks cryptic to me.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$ FOO="1234567890 one two three ABCDEF"
$ echo "$FOO" | sed "s|\(1.*0\).*\(A.*F\)|\2 \1|"
ABCDEF 1234567890
```

=> Tell SED to match `\(1.*0\).*\(A.*F\)` and replace it with `group2 group1`

A group declaration start with `\(` and finish with `\)`

- `\(1.*0\)` match any pattern than begin with "1" and finish by "0" and result is group 1
- `.*` match several characters (any kind)
- `\(A.*F\)` match any pattern than begin with "A" and finish by "F" and result is group 2

A group can be used for replace for example with \N where N is the group number.

- `\1` is group 1 so here '1234567890'
- `\2` is group 2 so here 'ABCDEF'

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is done using the `()` usually to substitute the matched (regex ) part later.

Using the basic regular expressions, the `()` should be escaped to get the special meaning ie `\(stuff\)`. For example in

```
echo "Bash Pitfalls" | sed -E 's/Pit(falls)/\1/'
```

give you

```
Bash falls
```

Note `-E` enable the use of Extended regex So i don't have to escape `()`.

Obviously, this is under-usage of the `()`, more practical usage would be to combine `()` with wildcards and number of occurences.

- Note the `{}` is used to count the occurrence of a pattern. Without extended regex they need to be escaped like `\{\}`.
- The `[]` in sed is to  mention ranges. for example `[0-9]` would match a number from 0 to 9, `[a-z]` any character from a to z and so on.

**More practical examples**

```
$ echo "Match" | sed -E 's/([HM]{1}at)ch/\1/'
Mat
$ echo "Hatch" | sed -E 's/([HM]{1}at)ch/\1/' 
Hat
$ echo "Catch" | sed -E 's/([HM]{1}at)ch/\1/'
Catch
```